# Why use System.out.print when I can just System.out.println?

Tags: java

I am having trouble understanding why I would need `System.out.print` if I can just use `System.out.println` to print what I need in one line.

Comment: What if you *don't* want to go to a new line after you printed?

Comment: Perhaps you don't want to print the line break yet? Just today I wrote code which wrote "Processing (filename)... " and then (on the same line) wrote the number of items in it afterwards. How would you do that with just `print`?

Comment: Let's say you want to print a list separated by commas (not newlines). Sure, you can build a string and then print that with `println`; but building the string takes up memory (etc) that you don't need to use if you print each separate item using `print`.

Comment: `System.out.println();` == `System.out.print("\n");`

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#out) is your friend.  From there, you can see that the type of System.out is [PrintStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html).  The documentation on the PrintStream page explains the difference between print and println.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print` doesn't move the cursor to a new line, which makes it useful when taking user input (just for example).

Answer (score 0):

print will keep on appending to same line whereas using println next line character is added by default.
For example, If you have array like ["Hi", "Hello"]
And you print this array using print then output would be "HiHello" whereas with println "Hi" and "Hello" will be printed on separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

To save you some time in future listing all available printing options on `System.out` stream:

```
String s = "Hellow world!";
double d = 3.77777;
System.out.println("println: " + s);

System.out.print("print: " + s);
System.out.print(" still on the same line. \n");

System.out.format("format: %s double is: %.3f %n", s, d);
System.out.format(Locale.FRANCE, "format with locale: double in France is: %.3f %n", d);
//printf is same as format just name is different for convinience
System.out.printf("printf: %s double is: %.3f %n", s, d);

System.out.append("append: " + s); 
System.out.append(" \n");

System.out.write(("write: " + s).getBytes());
```

Output:

```
println: Hellow world!
print: Hellow world! still on the same line. 
format: Hellow world! double is: 3.778 
format with locale: double in France is: 3,778 
printf: Hellow world! double is: 3.778 
append: Hellow world!
write: Hellow world!
```

For formatting refer [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) documentation.
Add to the list if I've missed something.